# Loop through ACF content

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to make a "related" module with Wordpress and [Advanced Custom Fields](http://advancedcustomfields.com) (ACF).

I've got the following loop:

```
<?php
  // Settings
  $categories = get_the_category();
  if ( count($categories) < 2 ) {
      $cat = $categories[0]->cat_ID;
  } else {
      $cat = $categories[1]->cat_ID;
  }
  $query = new WP_Query('cat='. $cat);
?>

<section class="related">
  <?php // The loop
    if ($query->have_posts()):
      while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

    // The content part
    if (have_rows('content')):
      while (have_rows('content')) : the_row();

      // Only print cover
      if (get_row_layout() === 'cover'):
        // Cover content...
      endif;

    // End: The content part
      endwhile;
    endif;

    // End: The loop
      endwhile;
      // Reset loop, keep Wordpress from looping through unwanted modules
      wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;

  ?>
</section>
```

I want the loop to only print the *cover* module, instead it prints all the fields inside the *content*-module, which is a *flexible content field*. Am I overseeing something that causes it to loop other modules apart from *cover*?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by pulling the while-loop out of `// The content part`